# Save the result of raster calculator as an memory layer in pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, memory-layer

I am using QGIS raster calc as below. Now I am saving it as a tiff. But is there a way that I can save it as a memory layer?

I want to refer to that resulting memory layer and polygonize it, and upload it to postgis server. Because I am building a plugin so I don't want user to specify a folder to save the tif.

```
layer = QgsRasterLayer(path_of_image, 'input')
name = layer.name()
resultinglayer = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
resultinglayer.ref = name + "@1"
resultinglayer.raster = layer
resultinglayer.bandNumber = 1
entries = [resultinglayer]
calc = QgsRasterCalculator('(%s@1)*0' % name, 
                          'C:/tom/ras.tif',
                          'GTiff', 
                          layer.extent(), 
                          layer.width(), 
                          layer.height(), 
                          entries)
calc.processCalculation()
```

Comment: Are you opposed to using a raster calculator from the **Processing** plugin?

Comment: that one doesnt seem to let me band 1 * 0, does it?

Comment: Not so sure but atleast you found a workaround :)

Answer (score 3):

I just found a workaround, may not be the best way, it gets the environment variable and find the temporary path

```
import os
temp_path = os.environ['TEMP']
```

then just save the output in that temp_path.